# Why isn't the R function sink() writing a summary output to my results file?

Tags: r, sink

Edit: This problem doesn't seem to be reproducible at this point, but I've updated this question to a more concise example that illustrates what the behavior was, in case anyone encounters a similar issue.

```
sink("res4.txt")
    cat("Here are my results:\n")
    summary(mtcars)
sink()
```

The `sink("~/R/res4.txt")` function in the last line will store the `"Here are my results"` line, but not the `summary(res4)` line in the `.txt` file.

Typing `summary(mtcars)` produces the correct data set, and I don't understand why the output of `summary(mtcars)` isn't included.

Comment: Are you running this non-interactively? Do you mean to have `print(summary(res4))`?

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks, that works. I didn't realize that I needed the `print` function because `summary(res4)` generates the same output in the console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are as many summary functions as there are  regression procedures and many of them use `cat` with would not get into a value returned. My suggestion is to use cat and capture.output both of which have a `file` destination parameter and an `append` option:

```
cat("Here are my results:\n", file="~/R/res4.txt")
capture.output( summary(res4), file"~/R/res4.txt", append=TRUE)
```

Comment: Greate, the "capture.output" function circumvents problems related to "sink" in bat mode and Rnoweb!